# Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I have an identity server which will receive request from native applications, now I'm testing with a UWP App, but it throws an error saying that the redirect URI is invalid, reading through the docs I found nothing but when I read the code of the demo site I noticed that it had a custom implementation of the IReturnUriParser, my question is, do I need to implement my own service to validate those cases on which the native apps are calling the server or what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to stop the app from navigating to the redirect URI. Validate the redirectURI it try to navigate is same as the redirect URI configured. Even I haven't tried UWP, You should be able to use events in the browser window to stop navigation, validate, and continue the program in the desired path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect URI that the client uses must match the pre-registered one. When you turn on logging it will tell you the allowed vs the actual requested URI.

Comment: I am having the same issue...UWP client, OidcClient2, IS4 server based on this sample: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Config.cs. The redirect URI's in the sample are "https://notused". So I'm confused between the sample and the comment about making sure the URI's must match the pre-registered one. ??? The UWP client sample shows a dynamically obtained Uri that ends up getting used as the redirect uri via OidClient2: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/master/Uwp/UwpSample/MainPage.xaml.cs#L33.

Comment: This might look like a dynamic value - but it is static (based on app identity). Whatever this call returns is the redirect URI you need to register with IdentityServer.

Comment: Ah, sure, makes sense that it's actually going to return the same thing every time. But I'm assuming it's not returning "notused" which appears to be what the server is configured to allow?

Comment: It did work for me to add the "ms-app://..." big long Uri for the UWP app to the list of RedirectUris on the server Client config. Rumor is that the value returned from GetCurrentApplicationCallbarUri() can change, but so far on 2 machines its the same for me. Still not quite understanding why the sample uses "notused" as the value here (and it still works!).

Comment: Rumor? ;) It is based on the signing cert - so it will only change, if you change your cert. "notused" works because my demo server is in - eh - "demo mode".

Comment: Hah :-) Ok got it. That makes me feel better I'm not missing something magical... Appreciate the help!

Comment: please have a look log "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:50496/signin-oidc\n{\r\n  \"RedirectUri\": \"http://localhost:50496/signin-oidc\",\r\n  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [],\r\n  \"SubjectId\": \"anonymous\",\r\n  \"RequestedScopes\": \"\",\r\n  \"Raw\": {\r\n    \"client_id\": \"mvc\",\r\n    \"redirect_uri\": \"http://localhost:50496/signin-oidc\",\r\n    \"response_type\": \"code id_token\",\r\n    \"scope\": \"openid profile\",\r\n    \"response_mode\":

Comment: I added the ""ms-app://..." Uri for the UWP app to the list of RedirectUris on the server Client Config.cs and when I ran my UWP it failed logging the following error message on generated log file in "logs" folder in the server:

   fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Invalid redirect_uri: ms-app://s-1-15-2-795742851-4271362196-158997185-4079463821-3407228175-4045361926-1486451071/
{
        "ClientId": "native.hybrid",

What am I missing? 

Second question: What Uri should I set under PostLogoutRedirectUris for the same server Client config?